# 'System testing' app doesn't work in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04

Just installed Ubuntu 13.04 64 and decided to run 'System Testing'(in dash type 'system testing') but it doesn't seem to be working.

It's stuck at 'Gathering information from your system':

[image]

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

- Kill all running instances of `checkbox-qt`: `pkill checkbox-qt`. Please note that a python process is also started, you have to kill that too:

```
$ ps fax | grep check
3796 pts/3    S+     0:00      \_ grep --color=auto check
3761 ?        Sl     0:00 python3 /usr/share/checkbox/run /usr/share/checkbox/config/checkbox-qt.ini
```

- Start `checkbox-qt` from a terminal window. (By opening a terminal window and typing: `checkbox-qt`.)
- Note the following output:

```
$ checkbox-qt
SYSTEM TESTING: Please enter your password. Some tests require root access to run 
properly. Your password will never be stored and will never be submitted with test 
results. PASSWORD:
```

- Enter your password at the terminal and the test should continue.

Comment: Your solution works! THanks. But just out of curiosity why does it work from command line and not in GUI?

Comment: I just have searched through Launchpad and found this bug report: [Checkbox prompts for sudo password in terminal](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/checkbox/+bug/1174411). [Another report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/checkbox/+bug/1097816) says: „`gksu` is deprecated for the desktop in favour of `pkexec`. We need to switch Checkbox over to it to avoid falling victim to bugs”. So I think since `gksu` is missing from Raring, it falls back to terminal.