# System Testing doesn't start

Tags: checkbox

I'm working on an Acer Aspire E 15 on which I have installed, in dual boot, Ubuntu Studio 14.04 and Windows 8.1.

I downloaded System Testing and tried to start it, since I need to check my audio card.

When I click on its icon in the menu, basically nothing happens.

I initially installed it trough the command `sudo apt-get install checkbox-qt`. After seeing it didn't work I uninstalled it from the Ubuntu Software Center and reinstalled it from there. Seeing it still wasn't working I uninstalled it again and tried to install it together with all of its optional things (the ones you have to check or uncheck in the USF). Still it isn't working. When I click on it, absolutely nothing happens.

This might interest you. Notice that "comando non trovato" in italian is "command not found".

```
alex@Sargon:~$ checkbox-qt
checkbox-qt: comando non trovato
alex@Sargon:~$ checkbox
usage: checkbox [-h] [--version] [--providers {all,stub}] [-v] [-D] [-C]
                [-T LOGGER] [-P] [-I]

                {sru,check-config,script,dev,checkbox-cli,driver-test-suite-cli,certification-server,service}
                ...
checkbox: error: too few arguments
```

The command to start it should be `checkbox-qt`, not `checkbox`. So I don't know what exactly is happening when i run the `checkbox` command, but clearly we can see that there is no `checkbox-qt` command.

Also, I tried to follow the steps indicated in [this other thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/317681/system-testing-app-doesnt-work-in-ubuntu-13-04), but I think that that solution isn't related with mine, since in the Process Manager I don't see any process whose name might seem related to System Testing/checkbox. Anyway, I tried to follow those steps, but nothing happens. I also don't have any python process to kill:

```
alex@Sargon:~$ ps fax | grep check
24238 pts/0    S+     0:00                  \_ grep --color=auto check
```

How should I proceed? I'd really need to use that program to test my hardware, so what I need is, of course, a way to repair System Testing and use it.

**EDIT:**

I found out this: I saw from the menu settings that when I click on System Testing the command being executed is `checkbox-gui`. So I entered that command from a terminal and this happened:

```
alex@Sargon:~$ checkbox-gui
checkbox-gui: error while loading shared libraries: libQt5Xml.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I guess that's the issue.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to solve this one on my own.

As revealed trough `apt-file`, the missing library is part of the `libqt5xml5` package:

```
alex@Sargon:~$ apt-file search libQt5Xml.so.5
libqt5xml5: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Xml.so.5
libqt5xml5: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Xml.so.5.2
libqt5xml5: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Xml.so.5.2.1
```

So to solve the problem I just had to go with `sudo apt-get install libqt5xml5`. After that, the issue was solved.